# scrolling a readonly cell in NSTableview?

Tags: cocoa, tableview

I have a table that the user should not be able to edit directly (although user actions may   cause changes).   One column may contain a string too long for any reasonable size cell, so to see everything there, the user needs to scroll the cell (using arrow keys, for example).

If I make either the column or cell not editible, I loose the ability to scroll the cell.
If I make it editable, of course, I loose the ability to keep the user from changeing it.

(I'm using NSArray controller and a couple of NSObject controllers to get from the model to the table view using bindings.  Binding compliance via @property(copy) and @synthesize.  Updating the model with setXXXX:xxx).

Thanks,

John Velman

Comment: It seems I can accomplish what I want by setting the column editable, the cell selectable but not editable, and the cell layout "wrap".  Then by double clicking, the user can see the wrapped lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with letting the table display tooltips for overflowed contents? This is automatic as of 10.5 if I recall correctly, else you can use the delegate method [-tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for better control.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua.  I had heard seen a reference to this, but didn't quite 'get it' for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua (continued): For me this has a problem of design esthetics:  The cells are displaying a string for an object using my custom formatter.  To display the expansionFrameWithFrame:inView: tool tip, the custom formatter is called twice: once to unformat and return an object of the represented class, and once to get the string to appear in the tool tip.  I can certainly live with this, and I can sort of understand why its done this way, but I kind of don't like it.   Thanks again.